# Получение cookies при аутентификации Vksdk android

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, android-vksdk

Возникла небольшая проблемка с Vksdk. Мне нужно получить куки такие как: remixstid, remixmdevice, remixlang, remixlhk в onActivityResult, пример ниже

```
if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, object:VKCallback<VKAccessToken> {
    override fun onResult(res:VKAccessToken) {
       //Здесь нужно получить куки
    }
    override fun onError(error:VKError) {}
}))
    {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

С этим sdk работаю меньше недели, точно не знаю можно ли вообще получить куки

Comment: По идее это невозможно. Кук не будет и получить их можно только авторизуясь через браузер. Т.к. на мобилах куки не используются, то их SDK вам никак и не даст.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ясненько, спасибо за ответ